# tlmgr and apt-get

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu, linux

I use LaTeX on a computer running Ubuntu Linux 14.  To install [the extension 'standalone'](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone), I can do

1. `apt-get`

I could determine that 'standalone' extension is included in the 'texlive-latex-extra' package by

```
apt-file search standalone.sty
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.sty
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latext-extra
```

Or

2. Use `tlmgr`

Install the package using `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr update --self --all
tlmgr install standalone
```

Is one method preferred than the other?

Comment: If you install a  "vanilla"   TeXLive 2015, use tlmgr and never use apt-get. If you install the default texlive from ubuntu .deb packages, is better use  only .deb packages (and probably you do not have tlmgr, at least this was true some time ago...)

Comment: I think it is no longer true.  I installed texlive-full using apt-get in Ubuntu 14.04 and I have tlmgr.  I believe it is part of texlive-base package.

Comment: Definitely stick to `apt` if you use your distro's package manager. Use `tlmgr` only if you really have to and understand the consequences. Vanilla is more straightforward, in my opinion, and a lot less trouble.

Comment: With `tlmgr` under a TeX distribution provided by Debian will just install packages for the user and not system-wide.

Comment: Accorrding to the [official documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) Ubuntu 14.04 comes with TL 2013. Please install vanilla TeXLive 2015 and then use tlmgr.

Comment: I was not sure if I had seen `tlmgr` in some recent Debian-like distro but then  I did not mind because I was focused in removing `texlive*.deb` to install the vanilla version. But now I'm curious: Only 3 years ago Norbert Preining (main `tlmgr` developer) [whas reluctant](https://lists.debian.org/debian-tex-maint/2012/04/msg00425.html)  to the idea of have two package managers (apt and tlmgr) working together. What has changed since then?

Comment: @doed Sorry by the cross-talk. My comment do not follow  Schröder's  comment but those of  Computist and egreg, because I was unsure in my first comment if `tlmgr` is installed now by Debian packages.

Comment: @doed  But the last Ubuntu is not 14.04, but 15.04 (Vivid Vervet).I have just checked that really  there are a `/usr/bin/tlmgr` in  `texlive-base` package in Debian stretch and Linux Mint 17.2 (Rafaela).  Shorcut without install .deb packages: `sudo apt-file list texlive-base | grep tlmgr`

Comment: @Fran please, if you installed 15.04, (I understand it implements the new systemd? but it's not LTS) could you please give the best-you-can-unbiased stance about the new version? not enough product reviews.

Comment: @doed this is off-topic here, but if it help.... I tested the 15.05 only a couple of days, just to remeber that I hate the evolution of Ubuntu in last versions.  Actually I prefer Linux Mint or  pure Debian. Just my opinon, but unbiased (see DistroWatch statistics).

Comment: @Fran they are all the **same**, in the broad sense, except proprietary philosophies. All GNU based with different package managers. But my main concern is systemd here.

Comment: @doed Yes, systemd is predetermined in 15.04 as well as in Linux Mint 17.2 and Debian 8. They are all the same in the sense they are all based in Debian with the package-manager (I mean apt-get , not the software center), but differences are not only proprietary philosophies. Ask yourself why Ubuntu become so popular time ago, but in the last four year Linux Mint is the king, and the traditional "betê noire" of Debian is the 2nd place, over the  "Linux for "humans beings".

Comment: :D this is definitely not on topic. shame on you, you started it :) @Fran, but why go to those lengths? it all depends what you consider a king. Look in England for example. Seriously. Get rid of GNU and good luck with that.; I'll wait for your postcard in the mail. Make sure you say cheese. Can a sustainable Unix-based system survive? Of course. You still have BSD. And you know what? it's all good.